# The Unity launcher won't respond to mouse

Tags: unity, launcher

The launcher sidebar has stopped working, although it pops out when I put the mouse on the left. It seems to be transparent. A click just affects whatever's running underneath and the bar pops back in.

I have Firefox, Rythymbox and Transmission running. It was working a while ago when I opened them. Then I tried to click on the Update Manager and got no response.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should tweak the available options at *System Settings > Appearance > Behavior (tab)*

Some very useful options regarding the Launcher are located there, including sensitivity. Good luck.

Comment: thanks. I've done that and now the launcher is there all the time, but the buttons still don't work - it is clicking on whatever is running behind them as if they weren't there

Comment: Well, I can't help further since I'm not using Unity myself. Hope someone else can assist you!